# run telegram simple bot

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

When I run the code below the following error message is displayed:

```
import telebot
#------------------#
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN") 
#------------------#
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "hello, how can I help you?")
#------------------#
bot.polling(True)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/PC/Desktop/telegram bot/bot.py", line 1, in <module>

import telebot

  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 816
@util.async()

  ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so what is wrong here? I have installed pyTelegramBotAPI

I wrote it with vs code and I wanted to create a simple bot

Answer (score 0):

> Do  `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` into your terminal/CMD to install telebot and then your code will run fine

```
import telebot

# ------------------#
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")


# ------------------#
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "hello, how can I help you?")


# ------------------#
bot.polling(True)
```

Comment: thank you it helped me. first I uninstalled it then I installed it from terminal